# Websocket scalability, broadcasting concerns

Tags: scalability, websocket

If you have a complex requirement set with many users(&servers) how will your websocket infrastructure (server[s]) will scale, especially with broadcasting?

Of course, broadcasting is not part of the any websocket spec but it's there even in basic chat examples (a.k.a. hello world for websocket).

Client side (asking for new data) solution still seems more scalable than server side (broadcasting) solution with websockets' low latency and relatively cheap (http headerless) nature.

Edit:

OK, just think that you want to replace all your ajax code with websocket implementations which may mean that so many connections within so many different contexts. This adds enormous complexity to your system if you want to keep track of every possible scenario for broadcasting.

Low (network/thread etc) level implementation suggestions are also part of the problem not the solution, because this means you have to code a special server unlike general http servers.

Moreover, broadcasting brings some sort of stateful nature to the table which can't easily scale. Think about adding more servers and load balancing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Scaling realtime web solutions can be a complex problem but one that services like [Pusher](http://pusher.com) (who I work for) have solved, and one that there are most definitely solutions defined for [self hosted realtime web solutions](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#self-hosted) - the [PubSub paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) is well understood and has been solved many times and in order to solve the problem there needs to be some state (who is subscribing to what). This paradigm is used in broadcasting the the types of scenarios that you are talking about.

[image: Broadcasting diagram]

Realtime web technologies have been built with large amounts of simultaneous connections in mind - many from the ground up. If you wanted to create a scalable solution you would most likely use an existing realtime web server that supports WebSockets, in the same way that it's highly unlikely that you would decide to implement your own HTTP Server you are unlikely to want to implement your own server which supports WebSockets from scratch.

Dedicated Realtime web servers also let you separate your application logic from your realtime communication mechanism (separation of concerns). Your application might need to maintain some state but the realtime technology deals with managing subscriptions and connections. How communication between the application and the realtime web technology is achieved is up to you but frequently messages queues are used and specifically [redis](http://redis.io) is very popular in this space.

HTTP polling may conceptually be easier to understand - you can maintain statelessness and with each HTTP poll request you specify exactly what you are looking for. But it most definitely means that you will need to start scaling much sooner (adding more resource to handle the load).

WebSocket polling is something I've not considered before and I don't think I've seen it suggested anywhere before either; the idea that the client should say "I'm ready for my next set of data and here's what I want" is an interesting one. WebSockets have generally taken a leap away from the request/response paradigm but there may be scenarios where the increased efficiency of WebSockets and request/response using them may have some benefits. The [SocketStream](https://github.com/socketstream/socketstream) application framework might be worth a look as it might be relevant; after the initial application load all communication is performed over WebSockets which means that event basic request/response functionality uses WebSockets.

[image: SocketStream logo]

However, since we are talking about broadcasting data we need to go back to the PubSub paradigm where it makes much more sense to have active subscriptions and when new data is available that new data is distributed to those active subscriptions (pushed). All your application needs to know is if there are any active subscriptions or not in order to decide whether to publish the data or not. That problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of websockets is that you keep a persistent connection with each client.  When there is new data that you want to send to every client, you already know who all the clients are so you should just send it.

It sound like you want each client to constantly be sending requests to the server for new data.  Why?  It seems like that would waste everyone's bandwidth and I don't know why you think it will be more scalable.  Maybe you could add more detail to your question like what kind of information you are broadcasting, how often, how many bytes, how many clients, etc.

Why not just consider an open websocket connection to be like a standing request from the client for more data?

Comment: IMHO, "Knowing who all the clients are" not that easy in server side websocket development. You have to keep track of everybody in their context efficiently and also having more than one server makes it more complex.

IMO, asking for new data is more scalable because your server implementation doesn't have to know about clients so that you can easily add new servers. And again, it's not really waste of bandwidth if you keep it small and you can with http headerless websocket.

Comment: No matter what you do, the server has to know about the clients because you have to keep a list of the open sockets.  Without a list of open sockets, you wouldn't be able to listen for incoming data from them (e.g. you won't know what list of file descriptors to pass to the `select` or `epoll` functions).  You also need to keep track of a buffer for incoming and outgoing data I think.  You can't just forget about open TCP/IP connections.  Since you're keeping track of that list anyway, it shouldn't be too hard to add some of your own identification data to that list, if needed.

Comment: You're nearly mixing session and socket concepts; first one is application level and the latter is network level as you know. In practice you don't wanna go that deep, neither do i. IMHO, it's better to think this problem in application level.

Comment: try libevent. it will allow to scale your websocket server. It uses underlying event notification mechanisms like epoll without the need of a big footprint for each open connection.

Comment: @FilipeSantos, I prefer [netty.io](http://netty.io) which is also an asynchronous event-driven network application framework. I guess i'm not clear about the problem, so i'll update the question.

Comment: The more I think about Ahmet's comments the more I disagree with them.  If you want to really carefully separate your "application level" from the "network level" you can do that and still keep track of the clients.  When the application level determines the identity of a client, it should give some sort of identity string to the network level, and the network level can store it with the file descriptor of the socket.  Then the application level should be able to get all those strings back at any time to tell which clients are connected.  The network level wouldn't know what the strings are.

Comment: I originally interpreted the OP's question to be about websocket technology (i.e. how to keep track of the state of a websocket).  With the edit, the question seems to be just be asking for some pre-built solutions that will help him scale up his realtime website, and some vague concerns about whether scaling is even possible.